# C# Instantly use comboBox entry

Tags: c#

Simply put, I want to use the value of the `ComboBox` as soon as it is selected to change some other values in the form.

Problem is, when I'm using `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged()`
the value of the box gets updated *after* this method terminates. So if I were to put my method `changeSomeOtherStuff(comboBox1.SelectedItem)` in there, it would get "" as parameter.

A workaround would be to insert another button that starts the method.

But there has to be an efficient way to instantly call the function with the selected value, right?

Comment: Did you tried to use `ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted`?

Comment: @Fabio I did now and it almost achieved what I wanted. Only problem now is that somehow my follow-up function always gets the previous value. E.g. When I select 4 at first, nothing happens (previous is empty) and if I select 7 after that, my function gets executed with the value 4. Happens with other events like DropdownClosed too.

Comment: Note that the [tag:visual-studio] tag description says *"DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio."* Please [edit] your question to remove it.

Comment: Show the code, please. Difficult to help without the code. `ComboBox.SelectedItem` will always return  currently selected value. There are possibly something else happened in your code which put comboBox in the inconsistent state.

Comment: @Fabio it's literally nothing more than this:         `private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = comboBox1.Text;
        }`

Comment: Don't use `comboBox1.Text`, use `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectionChanged event of combobox and in this method you can use combobox.text or selected item.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it by starting a new thread and letting it sleep for 10ms so that the other thread would finish running the method and updating the box:

```
private void comboBox1_DropdownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(updateBox);
    t.Start();


}


private void updateBox()
{
    Task.Delay(10);
    Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        textBox1.Text = Defaults.Defaults.DefaultOutputContainer(comboBox1.Text);
    }));

}
```

The Invoke part is to be able to access the comboBox1 even though it belongs to the main thread.